# MYSQL: How to get unique values to date grouped by date?

Tags: mysql

I need to find month by month way of showing year to date unique values. For example:

```
created_at   value
01-01-2012       a
01-01-2012       b
01-01-2012       a

01-02-2012       a
01-02-2012       a
01-02-2012       a

01-03-2012       c
01-03-2012       b
01-03-2012       b

01-04-2012       d
01-04-2012       e
01-04-2012       f
```

Should output:

```
Month   Monthly unique  Year to date unique
1       2               2
2       1               2
3       2               3
4       3               6
```

For monthly unique it is just a matter of group by and unique(), but it won't work for year-to-date this way. Year-to-date may be achieved by using for loop and filtering month by month since the beginning of the year, but it's a bad way I want to omit.

MRE:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    val varchar(5),
    month int
);
(STR_TO_DATE('1-01-2012', '%d-%m-%Y'), 'a'),
(STR_TO_DATE('1-01-2012', '%d-%m-%Y'), 'b'),
(STR_TO_DATE('1-01-2012', '%d-%m-%Y'), 'a'),
(STR_TO_DATE('1-02-2012', '%d-%m-%Y'), 'a'),
(STR_TO_DATE('1-02-2012', '%d-%m-%Y'), 'a'),
(STR_TO_DATE('1-02-2012', '%d-%m-%Y'), 'a'),
(STR_TO_DATE('1-03-2012', '%d-%m-%Y'), 'c'),
(STR_TO_DATE('1-03-2012', '%d-%m-%Y'), 'b'),
(STR_TO_DATE('1-03-2012', '%d-%m-%Y'), 'b'),
(STR_TO_DATE('1-04-2012', '%d-%m-%Y'), 'd'),
(STR_TO_DATE('1-04-2012', '%d-%m-%Y'), 'e'),
(STR_TO_DATE('1-04-2012', '%d-%m-%Y'), 'f');
```

I created this, which gives me desired output:

```
select value, month
from 

(
select count(distinct(val)) as value, count(distinct(month(created_at))) as month from t1 where month <=1 union
select count(distinct(val)) as value, count(distinct(month(created_at))) as month from t1 where month <=2 union
select count(distinct(val)) as value, count(distinct(month(created_at))) as month from t1 where month <=3 union
select count(distinct(val)) as value, count(distinct(month(created_at))) as month from t1 where month <=4 

) t2
```

But it's also awful and inconvenient for filtering the main table.
How to do it in efficient way?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: That said, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Good point, MRE added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select 
    d.month as 'Month', 
    count(distinct d.value) as 'Monthly unique', 
    ytdu as 'Year to date unique'
from data d
  join (
    select y.month, count(distinct d2.value) as ytdu
    from data y
      join data d2 on d2.month<=y.month
    group by y.month
  ) as q
where d.month=q.month
group by d.month, ytdu
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gqFSRDhaqMmbKupJKjmmbP/0)

Comment: working, but its many times slower than my clumsy proposition when tested on a large table

Comment: Why not show how your actual table looks like (including indexes).

Comment: only difference is id instead of value and table size, as we speak about millions of records. and month(created_at) instead of month

Comment: In order to get better answers, you should follow Strawberry's advise and show the exact  table definition. Having month(created_at) instead of month number changes how optimizer treats the query in case you have indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the expected result by performing subqueries for "Monthly unique" and "Year to date unique" and then combining the results.

```
select
  s1.month as "Month",
  s1.cnt as "Monthly unique",
  s2.cnt as "Year to date unique"
from
  -- for "Monthly unique"
  ( select month,count(distinct value1) as cnt
      from table1 group by month) as s1
  inner join
  -- for "Year to date unique"
  ( select t2.month,count(distinct t1.value1) as cnt
      from table1 as t1 cross join table1 as t2
        on t1.month<=t2.month
      group by t2.month) as s2
  on s1.month=s2.month
```

[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/anZPSoTNwCC19Pf998KiA/0)

Comment: working, but its many times slower than my clumsy proposition when tested on a large table